Getting error fsck.crypto_LUKS doesn't exist after re-encrypting rootfs in my Pop_OS installation
I have re-encrypted successfully the rootfs of my earlier installed Pop_OS! 22.04 installation using this post https://www.reddit.com/r/pop_os/comments/ljxxom/encrypt_hard_disk_after_the_installation/:
# e2fsck -f /dev/sdXY
# resize2fs -M /dev/sdXY
# cryptsetup-reencrypt /dev/sdXY --new --reduce-device-size 4096S
# cryptsetup open /dev/sdXY cr_disk

so now I have luks2 encrypted disk:
# cryptsetup -v status cr_disk
/dev/mapper/cr_disk is active and is in use.
  type:    LUKS2
  cipher:  aes-xts-plain64
  keysize: 256 bits
  key location: keyring
  device:  /dev/sdXY
  sector size:  512
  offset:  4096 sectors
  size:    194934784 sectors
  mode:    read/write

I've mounted the encrypted disk
# mount /dev/mapper/cr_disk /mnt

edited /mnt/etc/crypttab
cr_disk UUID=YOUR_LUKS_DISK_UUID none

modified /mnt/etc/fstab by replacing UUID of the disk
and tried to re-generate initramfs:
# mount --bind /dev /mnt/dev
# mount --bind /proc /mnt/proc
# mount --bind /sys /mnt/sys
# mount --bind /run /mnt/run
# mount /dev/sda1 /mnt/boot/efi
# chroot /mnt
# update-initramfs -u

And here I am getting error:
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-6.9.3-76060903-generic
W: /sbin/fsck.crypto_LUKS doesn't exist, can't install to initramfs

So, everything works fine: the system boots up, prompts the password, unlocks it. However, when I run update-initramfs -u command it is constantly claiming with the above mentioned error or warning.
Is it connected with the previously selected luks2 version or with what? Is it serious or can be ignored?

Does your /etc/fstab still refer to your root filesystem as /dev/sdXY? It should now refer to /dev/mapper/cr_disk instead.
The error message suggests the initramfs generator still expects to find an unencrypted root filesystem and is trying to auto-detect a suitable filesystem checking program for it. But it detects an encrypted filesystem (crypto_LUKS) and mechanically tries to install a corresponding checker into the initramfs, causing the error message.
It makes no sense to attempt to run a filesystem checker on /dev/sdXY once it's been encrypted, as apart from the LUKS header, the encrypted data should be essentially indistinguishable from random data. The fileystem can be checked only after unlocking the encryption, using the /dev/mapper/cr_disk device.

Thanks for the hint and explanation! It makes sense.
